# Mysql database timestamp query using php

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql database timestamp query using php

I inserted into database a timestamp value set to 3 hours a head as follows

```
//For 3 hours ahead of time
$reciever_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours'));
```

now once its upto 3 hours, i need to echo "3 hours is due" but the code below keeps echoing "its not yet 3 hours" even though
 3 hours is due. any help

```
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sectona", "secBBN", "sectonadb");
$q = "SELECT id,reciever_time FROM indextime WHERE id='10'";
$qu = mysqli_query($link, $q);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qu, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
       $timest = $row['reciever_time'];

    }

//60secx10min is 600milisec
//60secx30min is 1800
// 30 min = 1800
// 1 hour = 1800 x2
//12 hour = 3600 x12
//1 day = 3600 x24


$time = strtotime($timest);
$curtime = time();




// execute data that is due in 3 hours
if(($curtime-$time) >= 10800) {
  print "3 hours is due then update";
}


else{

  print "its not yet 3 hours";
}


?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$time` and `$curtime`? Try using `var_dump()`.

Comment: I before E except after C

Comment: @ficuscr Just like in `mysqli<(is_before)>connect` ;-)

Comment: Are you PHP server and MySQL on the same timezone?  Why calculate time in PHP at all?  Why not use MySQL time functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(($time - $curtime) >= -10800) {
  print "3 hours is due then update";
} else {
  print "its not yet 3 hours";
}
```

Only convert the `10800` to negative.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you want to use the the date_diff function to get the difference in time
try:

```
if(date_diff($time,$curtime) >= 10800){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","DBname");

$q = "SELECT id,reciever_time FROM indextime WHERE id='10' LIMIT 1";
$qu = $link->query($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($qu);
$id = $row->id;
$timest = $row->reciever_time; 
$time = strtotime($timest);
$curtime = time();
$message = ($curtime - $time) >= 10800 ? "3 hours is due then update" : "its not yet 3 hours";
print $message;
```